# Xamarin iOS Firebase Native linking failed

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

After updating the Firebase libraries, I'm getting the following errors:

> MTOUCH : error MT5210: Native linking failed, undefined symbol: _APMAnalyticsConfiguration. Please verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and native libraries are properly linked in.
> Blockquote
>
> MTOUCH : error MT5210: Native linking failed, undefined symbol: _APMAppMeasurementOriginFirebase. Please verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and native libraries are properly linked in.
>
> MTOUCH : error MT5210: Native linking failed, undefined symbol: _APMIsAnalyticsCollectionDeactivated. Please verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and native libraries are properly linked in.
>
> MTOUCH : error MT5210: Native linking failed, undefined symbol: _APMIsAnalyticsCollectionEnabled. Please verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and native libraries are properly linked in.
>
> MTOUCH : error MT5210: Native linking failed, undefined symbol: _APMMonitorLogTagOptionKey. Please verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and native libraries are properly linked in.
>
> MTOUCH : error MT5210: Native linking failed, undefined symbol: _APMSafelistedEventsOptionKey. Please verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and native libraries are properly linked in.

I've tried the following:

1. Deleting obj and bin folders
2. Cleaning the project
3. Initializing Firebase core (Firebase.Core.App.Configure();)

I've tried all linker behavior options.

I'm referencing the following Firebase libraries:

1. Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.Analytics (6.4.1)
2. Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.CloudMessaging (4.3.0)
3. Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.Core (6.6.6)
4. Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.DynamicLinks (4.0.8)
5. Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.Installations (1.1.1)
6. Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.InstanceId (4.3.3)

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: Were you able to get this working?

Comment: Take a look, maybe it would help: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/155755/visual-studio-2019-and-ios-native-linking-failed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, there isn't much that you can do in this case. The error is related to incorrect linking. The guys from Xamarin have messed up the bindings after one of the upgrades. You can read more about using native libraries in Xamarin [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/platform/binding-objective-c/) & more specifically [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/macios/binding/objective-c-libraries).

However, you can still do something to help - isolate which package caused the issue and from which version onwards it happens. Then, report it at the official GitHub repository for Google APIs [here](https://github.com/xamarin/GoogleApisForiOSComponents/).

P.S. I have gone through the [issues](https://github.com/xamarin/GoogleApisForiOSComponents/issues) and haven't seen this exact list of errors. There have been (and still are) a lot of binding issues, which are waiting to be fixed. So, in order to speed things up, discuss it with the devs from the issue and hopefully, they will be able to resolve it quickly.

Comment: Thanks, I'm checking the links.
In one the issues discussed, someone commented: "I have to delete XBD cache" - do you know how to do that?

Comment: Can you provide me with a link so that I can see the context?

Comment: https://github.com/xamarin/GoogleApisForiOSComponents/issues/385#issuecomment-626016278

Comment: Yes, as I thought. XBD refers to XamarinBuildDownload directory, which is located here `~/Library/Caches/XamarinBuildDownload`

Comment: Thanks! I will try that.